# Не работает jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, кодировка, jquery-ui, slider

У меня такая вот проблема. 
Вот JS-код:

```
'$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  values: [ 75, 300 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );'



<p>
<label for="amount">Price range:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly></p> 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

При всем этом slider на странице не появляется. 
Может ли быть проблема в том что на сайте подключенно другие библиотеки, а именно: 
-elevateZoom
-cycle
-swiper
-script (мои скрипты)

Comment: Подключения библиотек идет в точно таком же порядку, библиотека jquery-ui подключается сразу после подключения jquery

Comment: А в консоли есть JS ошибки ?

Comment: Ошибки есть. 'jquery-ui.js:1914 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
    at String.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.js:1914)
    at each (jquery.js:30)
    at Function.color.hook (jquery-ui.js:1913)
    at jquery-ui.js:1963
    at jquery-ui.js:2005
    at jquery-ui.js:14
    at jquery-ui.js:16'